# Processing huge data volume in Leaflet using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, frameworks, leaflet

I have a huge data volume that comes from a Java rest service called using ajax to get rendered on Leaflet however this is hanging the browser as the data is too large in volume, Could you please suggest any framework or something else related to JavaScript that I can make use of it.

I'm new to AngularJS and NodeJS, So don't know much about it.

Comment: What kind of volume are we talking here? I am dealing with a similar issue. I plan on using websockets though, have you thought about/taken a look at them? I think AJAX would require more Http requests compared to a websocket connection and so probably would be more slow. Websockets are a breeze to use as well.